# How to get rid of unused space after transform?

Tags: html, css, less

in an ongoing project I need to make a text going into the previous background image. (The text should go into the previous element by half of its own height) So far no problem

```
position: relative; top: -50%;
```

OR

```
transform: translateY(-50%)
```

do the trick.

But as this is the start of the page I of course will have content follow it. This Content gets e.g. a margin-top of 30px (all of this happens by adding classes in a CMS).

And the transform and position put the element optically further to the top. but the following element will adjust his placement to the original state of the transformed item.

Here´s a fiddle showing the problem:

```css
.red_box{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
.text_transformed{
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.text_margin_top{
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
body{
  background-color: #e5ceb0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="red_box">

  </div>
  <div class="text_transformed">
     Lorem Impusm
  </div>
  <div class="text_margin_top">
    Lorem Ipsum2
  </div>
</div>
```

"Lorem Ipsum2" is supposed to be 10px after the white background of the first text, but instead it is 10px beneath the "not-transformed" first text.

I googled alot but seem to find no solution.
The solution I currently go for is using margin-top: -NEGATIVEVALUE. But the problem here is I have to set the exact PX value to set the transformed element half into the previous.
This works fine for having fixed size of an element but since I have dynamic contet this is not the best solution....

Any ideas for pure CSS?

Comment: oh sorry, thought fiddle is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transforms move an element independent of the rest of the DOM.

Instead of `transform: -50%;` use margin instead:

```
margin-top: -50%;
```

The following elements should take up the space created by moving the target element up.

```css
.red_box{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
.text_transformed{
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -50%;
}
.text_margin_top{
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
body{
  background-color: #e5ceb0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="red_box">

  </div>
  <div class="text_transformed">
     Lorem Impusm
  </div>
  <div class="text_margin_top">
    Lorem Ipsum2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wait what? Why does it worked (had some try and error yesterday). - margin-top: 50%; (not negative) does a margin of half the screen-height, but with negative this works on element, why is that?